# Regular Expression for email subdomain match

Tags: regex, email, postgresql

Anyone know of a regular expression that will only match emails that contain a sub-domain in them?

**e.g.,**

`name@subdomain.domain.com` or `name@subdomain.domain.edu.au`

Preferably to use in [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql).

**I tried this:**

```
^[-+.0-9A-Z_a-z]+@[-+.0-9A-Z_a-z]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$
```

but it also matches `name@test.org`.

Comment: `^[-+.0-9A-Z_a-z]+@[-+.0-9A-Z_a-z]+.[A-Za-z]+.{2,4}$` try this.

Comment: doesnt match anything, i tried this: email ~  '(\w+\.?)+@(\w+\.){2,}\w{2,4}'
but in postgresql it returns nothing yet when i used rubular it worked. any ideas?

Comment: It'd help if you specified what the intent is - what you want this to achieve. The best answer depends a lot on what exactly you're using it for; in particular, reporting vs validation vs data cleaning are very different tasks.

Comment: So what about something like bob@somecomany.co.uk?  Is that a subdomain or not?

Comment: So you mean the the beginning of the string left of `@`, no matter if it is a "sub-domain" or not?

Answer (score 8):

Don't, not for validation purposes anyway. It'll only end in pain.

The only reasonable regular expression for validating an email address is one that looks for a "@" symbol and at least one period. Nothing else; even alphanumerics are pointless with the advent of [IDNs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name).

At minimum you need to define exactly what you mean by "subdomain". Everything is a subdomain. A subdomain of what? What is excluded and what is included?

How do you define "subdomain" vs "top level"? Do you mean "a subdomain of [a domain that is open to public registration](http://publicsuffix.org/learn/)" ? "A subdomain of a subdomain of a domain that is open to public registration" ? At what level of delegation does it become a subdomain for your purposes?

What about government domains, where the "public" that can register domains is very limited, and subdomains-of-subdomains-of-subdomains are the norm? What do you want to match?

How will you cope with the [new gTLDs](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/) and the fact that the list will change with time? Or with the addition/removal of ccTLDs? What about if a ccTLD changes its policy, beginning to sell direct descendant domains (eg "myname.au") instead of only selling specific sub-registries (eg "myname.org.au")? Will you be dynamically updating your regex, and if so how will you handle addresses that used to be valid and are no longer, or vice versa?

I run into idiotic email validation systems that even reject my main email address ringerc@ringerc.id.au  (no point munging it when it's already all over the 'net) despite it being an entirely valid .id.au domain.

Please don't create another one. If your intent isn't validation, that's cool, but *please* don't try to validate email address domains with a regex.

Comment: +1 for teaching taste (a feeling what's wrong and what's not)

Answer (score 3):

use this one:

```
(\w+@[\w.]+\w)
```

explain:

```
\w+      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) 
         (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))

@                        '@'

[\w.]+   any character of: word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _), '.' 
         (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible))

\w       word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _)
```

and for **PostgreSql** see [this link](http://planetearthsolution.com/binodsblog/2011/02/07/regular-expression-in-postgresql/), and [this](http://blog.sinjakli.co.uk/2011/02/13/email-address-validation-please-stop/). (seem be impossible).

Comment: and in postgresql: email ~ '(\w+@[\w.]+\w)'
?

Doesnt seem to work

Answer (score 2):

This simple regular expression does not guarantee valid email-addresses, but it eliminates much of the nonsense reliably: If the expression yields `FALSE`, the address is actually invalid:

```
SELECT 'name@subdomain.domain.edu.au' ~ E'^\\S+@subdomain\\.\\S{2,}+$'
```

```
^  .. start of string
\S+ .. one or more non-space characters
@subdomain .. literally
\. .. a literal dot
\S{2,}+ two or more non-space characters
$ .. end of string
```

All `\` doubled for [escape string syntax](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS).
And, unlike some other answer, it works in PostgreSQL. Tested with v9.1.4. Details in the manual [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS).

Like @Craig wrote: it's futile to attempt reliable validation. But you can still eliminate much nonsense.

One step further, eliminate multiple `@`:

```
E'^[^[:space:]@]+@subdomain\\.[^[:space:]@]{2,}+$'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a list if all top-level domains and their structure. The Mozilla project has such a list; it is several hundred lines, so incorporating it into a regex may be cumbersome, although certainly not impossible. https://wiki.mozilla.org/TLD_List update: superseded by http://publicsuffix.org/

Basically it is a link parser. It needs to look in text (from the database), find any text that matches email addresses or URL and turn them into links

Answer (score 0):

I think you could do it yourself, trying on the website:

Regex Tester http://regexpal.com/

You can try online...

Regards,
Victor Zurita M.

Comment: Handy tool, but not all regular expression dialects are the same or support the same things so that's of pretty limited utility. It doesn't even let you switch between pcre, extended posix regex, and posix regex.

Answer (score 0):

You should write regex to match the subdomain along with domain name and the dot following it. Like this:

`(([a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z0-9]{2,}\.)`

For matching entire email id, this is the regex:

`([a-z]+[a-z0-9]*[_\.]?[a-z0-9]+)@(([a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z0-9]{2,}\.)+[a-z]{2,}`

```
naveed@comquest:~$ echo -e "a_mb1@a.bc.abc.com\na2bc.xyz@a.bb.123.fr\na.123@abc.com.sg" | grep -E "([a-z]+[a-z0-9]*[_\.]?[a-z0-9]+)@(([a-z0-9]+\.)*[a-z0-9]{2,}\.)+[a-z]{2,}"
a_mb1@a.bc.abc.com
a2bc.xyz@a.bb.123.fr
a.123@abc.com.sg
```

You can find a detailed explanation [here](http://comquest.blog/grep-regular-expression-to-match-any-valid-email-id/)