# how to extract email from pdf

Tags: python, regex, email, pdfminer

I'm trying to extract email from a cv using pdfminer and regular expressions

```
from io import StringIO
from pdfminer3.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager, PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer3.converter import TextConverter
from pdfminer3.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer3.pdfpage import PDFPage
import re

def get_cv_email(self, cv_path):
    pagenums = set()
    output = StringIO()
    manager = PDFResourceManager()
    converter = TextConverter(manager, output, laparams=LAParams())
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(manager, converter)
    infile = open(cv_path, 'rb')
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(infile, pagenums):
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    infile.close()
    converter.close()
    text = output.getvalue()
    output.close()
    match = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[\w\.-]+', text)
    email = match.group(0)
    return email
```

The email is succesfully extracted for most of the resumes but it doesn't work correctly all the time

Example : jayantanathcdh@gmail.comEducationalQualification

**UPDATE:** How can I edit my regex to ignore what ever comes after the email if it starts with an uppercase

Comment: This answer might help you re-phrase the question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11453831/3564632. Definitely you have to decide a strategy on what you are expecting the emails to be, probably can define a list of all domains that you want to support and support that list. Or if you want more a generic solution you have to really keep updated the list with the latest. That answer that I linked should provide enough clearance I guess

Comment: In case you want to support just `.com` it might be easy to adjust the regex. In any case you should try to adjust the regex with the new intention you have

Comment: Can we assume that after every e-mail there's either a non-word or an uppercase word? Is that true?

Comment: in most cases yes

Comment: So that means 'no', unless you want a solution that work 'in most cases' :-)

Comment: Actually I tested the program with over 143 resumes, and only one had that error. How can I edit my regex to ignore what ever comes after the email if it starts with an uppercase ?

Comment: @AmineMessaoudi I posted an answer based on your last comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your last comment to match the email as you were matching until it finds an Upper case letter after `@` you can use this regex:

```
[\w\.-]+@[a-z0-9\.-]+
```

With an example:

```
import re
text = "jayantanathcdh@gmail.comEducationalQualification"
match = re.search(r'[\w\.-]+@[a-z0-9\.-]+', text)
email = match.group(0)

print(email)
#jayantanathcdh@gmail.com
```

Comment: It works. But if after the email there's a new line and after that line there's a word that starts with uppercase, what would happen then ? Will it take just the email ?

Answer (score 4):

Try with this: `\w+(?:[.-]\w+)*@\w+(?:[.-]\w+)+[.-][a-z_0-9]+(?=[A-Z]|(?!=[.-])\b)`

It should work as long as the last part of the email is lowercase. It will match until it is followed by a uppercase letter or a word boundary.

Also, the regex should be more accurate with the dashes and dots, and thus take care of things that should not be valid like `a-.@foo--a` etc.

You have a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/WkBh14/4/)

Comment: Thanks!! I equally enjoyed the demo part of it.  In first go, the expression was not that easy for me to understand.