# How to parse a PDF format web page using python and print it's content in a pretty format?

Tags: python-3.x, parsing, pdf, beautifulsoup

I want to parse a web page which is really a PDF file using python.
bellow is the link of a sample PDF web page:

http://www.jsu.edu/ire/factbook/JSUFactbook14-15.pdf

but when i want to parse the content of web page or print a part of it's text, the result is in unreadable format and contains some unfamiliar characters.

this is a part of my code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests_html import HTMLSession


    def search(url):
    
        session = HTMLSession()
        response = session.get(url, verify=False, timeout=2)
        
        if response is None:
            print('response empty')
            return
    
        content = response.content
        content = BeautifulSoup(content, "html.parser")
    
        content = str(content)
        print(content[:2000])

        location = content.find("University")

        return location


url = 'http://www.jsu.edu/ire/factbook/JSUFactbook14-15.pdf'
print(search(url))
```

I'm sure that the word "university" is in this PDF file but I can't find it and also when I print a part of it's text(2000 character), the output file is unreadable like this:

```
6885 0 obj
&lt;&gt;stream
h��W{PT�����ee�]���+"�    �A���5(�6�#e[�d���    �iL��j#�4�6ffmǶ�%i�tZj5�֚iG'IM[��w��]���Lgڿ�p�������c���YH��P]�4�K
�]^&amp;�_���錄
���=giʎV�����}�����I����$W���CBR)κ�����N�JN���T�
�2=����\z�R,�Z�)p9UZ����������3�}�d&lt;`�    ?_����%]�ű���I�~��&gt;��d�(|<lx##rq�5��o�j�i�eo�'9�ǘryk��z���� ="" f���*����#�7�߻h8����0s��\u���]+.�="B��~{J�&quot;��Ly�q93?'�" vy���0�����}�*��c��'="|y�ȝ!{��}�" wx�i�a΍8�=""
```

can anyone help me, how I can print the output in a pretty format and how I can find a specific word inside it?

Comment: Thank you, but actually i want to parse some pdf files like this one in an automatic way. is it another way to parse the whole page without downloading that file?
@KJ

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to extract text from pdf files with `Beautifulsoup` by first converting the file to html with [pdftohtml](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-pdftohtml/):

```
!apt-get install -y poppler-utils
!wget http://www.jsu.edu/ire/factbook/JSUFactbook14-15.pdf
!pdftohtml -s -i JSUFactbook14-15.pdf output.html

import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with open('/content/output-html.html') as html:
  soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
  
soup.find_all('p', text=re.compile(r"University"))
```

For automation just create a temp folder and delete the files after completion.

Comment: @KJ afaik this question is about parsing a pdf with BeautifulSoup. Feel free to post your own answer if you know better.

Comment: Thank you, so as I understood, I can't do this job just with python, is it correct?

If I had to be a little more specific, that was part of my code. In fact, I want to extract information from some sites with rejex, and my problem is that sometimes, ‌ web pages are PDF type.
@RJ Adriaansen

Comment: my main problem is to extract all email addresses from some sites using regex. I wrote a program with python which is working correctly unless we have a pdf web page. so the only thing I need is, how i can change my code in order to extract emails from pdf files. the "University" was just an example.  @KJ

Comment: RJ Adriaansen explained about a way which needs to use a tool (pdftohtml) outside of my code. so if i can do all the job just inside my python code, then i will get my answer.
@KJ

Comment: @Saeed That's actually a different question from what you asked in this thread. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55139685/how-to-extract-email-from-pdf). I hope your intentions are sound.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do what you are attempting is bypass the middlemen and run poppler pdftohtml direct, so I have only parsed the first two transfered pages (-f 1 -l 2) into html. (but the whole file will have been *transfered/downloaded in the background* (I need to be aware of that in case I find it stuck in a cache folder later.)

[image]

The command line in poppler utils is

```
pdftohtml -f 1 -l 2 -fmt png -p -c http://www.jsu.edu/ire/factbook/JSUFactbook14-15.pdf index.htm
```

Dont expect it to be fast it has to download the whole file to find and sort all the random objects on each page.

e.g If you are searching for that "first" Jacksonville State University it is in the first half of object number 6,855 and may be found above the word Book which is also part of the same object so both lines were either inserted as one or later merged into page 1 as is often the case when the cover is designed and added later using InDesign.

Once the file is downloaded, decrypted and sorted by pdftohtml then it can start composing a HTML for each page and add bookmarks for those pages. That is a slow process, and not much quicker if  you only parse page one by set `-l 1` in place of `-l 2`